# Index, for loops and making things look cleaner

Tags: python, django

I have a number of objects that represent various versions of a letter. Some of these versions have been printed (timedate stamped). If a letter (with all it's versions) has been printed I need to get the timedate stamp of the last printed version (easily done), and then the version number of the last printed version (currently making my code look like C++{shiver}).

So how do I make this look more pythonic (cleaner)

```
try:
    # get the lastest letter version that has been printed
    lv_temp = LV.objects.filter(letter=letter.id,printed_last__isnull=False).latest('id')
    # get the id's of all the letter versions for a particular letter
    lv_temp2 = LV.objects.filter(letter=letter.id).order_by('id')
    lv_temp4 = []
    # get all the letter version for a particular letter
    for lv_temp3 in lv_temp2:
        lv_temp4.append(lv_temp3.id)
    # get an array of the indexes and the pks
    for i,v in enumerate(lv_temp4) :
        # if the pk of the last printed version is the same one as in the loop...
        if lv_temp.id == v :
            # ...save the index as the version number
            lv_printed_ver = i
    lv_printed = lv_temp.printed_last
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    lv_printed = None
    lv_printed_ver = None
```

*(I used `lv_temp...` because I was getting angry how many times I had to pass things)*

Comment: Don't use variables named `temp[1-4]?` Use names with a meaning.

Comment: Also, building `lv_temp4` seems useless if it's just to iterate over it once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more pythonic way to generate the list of ids would be a list comprehension, replacing

```
lv_temp2 = LV.objects.all().order_by('id')
lv_temp4 = []
for lv_temp3 in lv_temp2:
    lv_temp4.append(lv_temp3.id)
```

with

```
lv_temp4 = [i.id for i in LV.objects.all().order_by('id')]
```

Then, assuming I understand your code correctly and you are looking for the index in the list that matches the id, you can do:

```
lv_printed_ver = lv_temp4.index(lv_temp.id)
```

HTH

Comment: Even better: Use a genex `lv_temp4 = (i.id for i in LV.objects.all().order_by('id'))` so you don't have to build a list and discard it immediately afterwards.

Comment: I'm making this as correct because I asked 'how do I make this cleaner?' not 'how can I re-think this to make less code?'

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is some django code.

In that case, you have a bigger problem than the syntax : the bit of code you show us gets a full table and then filter it in python code. You should not do that.

Your problem is that you use the position in the sql table as something meaningful. What you should do is have the version number explicitly inside the `LV` object.

Comment: I could do that and it would mean I would be hitting the database less

Answer (score 0):

I was going about this all wrong. Instead of:

```
# get the last printed letter version for a letter
# get all the letter versions for a letter
# loop over all the letter versions for a letter and extract their id
# loop over the letter versions id's and compare them to the id of the...
#     ... last printed letter version
# if they match save the position in the loop as the version number
```

And should have thought of it like this:

```
# get the last printed letter version for a letter
# count all the letter versions for a particular letter where their...
#    ... id's are less then the id of the last printed letter version...
#    ... and use this as the version number
```

This different way of thinking makes me end up with:

```
try:
    # get the lastest letter version that has been printed
    lv_temp = LV.objects.filter(letter=letter.id,printed_last__isnull=False).latest('id')
    # count the number of letter versions for a particular letter whos...
    #      ... id is less then the id of the last printed letter version
    lv_printed_ver = LV.objects.filter(letter=letter.id,id__lte=lv_temp.id).count()
    lv_printed = lv_temp.printed_last
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    lv_printed = None
    lv_printed_ver = None
```